# AWS Cognito Username and Password Authentication using PHP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito API, I trying to login using the code provided on this URL https://github.com/pmill/aws-cognito/blob/master/examples/login.php, and getting exception "Auth flow not enabled for this client" "InvalidParameterException", please let me know if I am missing something or doing something wrong, user was signed up and confirmed successfully but not able to login? If help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like there is some issue with your Userpool settings. In Cognito Userpool  console, select your Userpool. Go to **App Integration --> App client Settings** . Select your App Client. Under **OAuth2 --> Allowed OAuth flows**, select the first 2 options (Authorization code grant & Implicit grant. Also, under Allowed scopes select the ones you want to allow. You can select all of them for testing. Save the changes. This should fix the error (atleast the first one - "Auth flow not enabled for this client). See if you get any errors.

If you still get the error, then may be ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH is not enabled for your client. In your Userpool settings, go to **App Clients** (and not App Client Settings). Click on **Show Details** for your app client. Select the **ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH** option i.e. Enable sign-in API for server-based authentication and save. See if this fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I published one article on fixing this error on Linkedin. Here's the link: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/amazon-cognito-how-fix-error-auth-flow-enabled-client-malik/

My brief answer is: please check "Enable sign-in API for server-based authentication (ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH)" as shown in below picture.

[image]